Adding Apache Camel related configuration properties to Springboot application.yml
I struggle with the following:
I have a Springboot application kicking off Apache Camel routes connecting data sources to a database. This works well, but one data source is too slow (publishes values only every 120 secs), so the related Camel route runs into a shutdown.
From the Camel documentation I found out that I can configure the timeout in an application.properties file:
camel.main.shutdown-timeout = ###

With a default of 45 seconds. As far as I understand SpringBoot and because I am running the whole thing as SpringBootApplication, I cannot use application.properties, but have to use application.yml.
I tried to enter the camel main setting to myexisting application.yml like this:
spring:
    profiles: test
    enables: false
influxdb:
    ...
---
spring:
    profiles: prod
    enabled: true
    application:
        name: ArchivingConnector

influxdb:
    ...
camel:
    main:
        shutdownTimeout: 300
---
    ...

I face a similar situation with another camel springboot application connecting to a Kafka broker. This application shuts down immediately as discussed in many other threads. There, I added the property
camel.springboot.main-run-controller: true

Both to the application.yml and to an application.properties. I see that application.yml is being read. The corresponding debug output looks like this:
DEBUG [time...] (OriginTrackedYamlLoader) - Loading from YAML: class path resource [application.yml]
DEBUG [time...] (OriginTrackedYamlLoader) - Merging document (no matchers set): {spring={profiles={active=production}, main={lazy-initialization=false}, influx2db={url=http://server1:8086, token=TOKEN, org=ORG, bucket=BUCKET}}, kafka={server={hostname=server2, port=9092}}, camel.springboot.main-run-controller=true, camel.routecontroller.enabled=true, ...}
DEBUG [time...] (OriginTrackedYamlLoader) - Loaded 1 document from YAML resource: class path resource [application.yml]
DEBUG [time...] (ApplicationEnvironment) - Activating profiles [production]

However, this data I see in the debug output seems not to have any effect in the application. What do I have to do? Add annotations with the SpringBootApplication? Change the structure of application.yml?

Camel should understand this yaml syntax:
camel.main.shutdown-timeout: 300


I tried the syntax but it didn't work.
